# Code that finds missing files in a series

Tags: perl, scripting, series

I'm looking for a line of code that identifies missing files in a series of files and exports that list to a txt file.  For example: a directory called 1to100000 contains pdfs named 1,2...99999,100000 but is missing some from the series. I would like the script to report those missing files to a txt file. Ideally this would be an executable perl script.
Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Please be more clear. When you say "a directory called 1to100000 contains pdfs named 1,2...99999,100000", these are PDF files? What defines the series? Is the series defined only by the file name or the PDF files need to be parsed? Better questions produce better answers...

Comment: Integers. The series is a set of pdf files. The directory names aren't really relevant. There is a folder containing files x to x+10000 where those constraints are easily defined. If I want to know which files are missing from this continuous series, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count from 1 to 100000 and check to see if the file exists.

```
foreach my $num ( 1 .. 100000 ) { 
    my $fname = "1to100000/$num.pdf";
    print "missing $fname\n" unless -f $fname;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find 100000 stats will be substantially slower than 100000 readdirs.

Answer (score 3):

Using readdir:

```
my @expect = map "$_.pdf", 1..100000;
my %notfound;
@notfound{@expect} = ();

opendir my $dirh, "1to100000" or die "Couldn't open directory: $!";
while ( my $fname = readdir($dirh) ) {
    delete $notfound{$fname};
}

for my $fname (@expect) {
    if ( exists $notfound{$fname} ) {
        print "missing $fname\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of finding missing numbers in a range (Using Set::IntSpan).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Set::IntSpan;

# the last sector on disk
my $end_sect = 71127179;

# The complete range of sectors on the disk
my $range = Set::IntSpan->new( "0-$end_sect" );

# The ranges of used sectors
my $used = Set::IntSpan->new( 
'0-1048706,1048707-2097414,69078879-71127179' );

# Calculates the remaining unused sectors
my $unused = $range->diff( $used );

print $unused->run_list;
```